# Do we still need Node.js or NPM to use Appium?

Tags: mobile, android-emulator, appium

My Appium is not running. The code seems right, does not throw any errors. However, somehow it does not open the app in the emulator. Any help would be appreciated.

I have done everything except installing node.js or npm.

Answer (score 2):

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLzWG.png)
Have you provided the path of your apk file in your code? Might be appium unable to find out the exact path for which you want to open the app.